# Picking individual numbers from multi-digit numbers in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that would take the numeric column from my data frame ("rate") and tell me if any of the two-digit numbers contain a 5. It should return an X5 if the statement is true or "" if false. I have tried `ifelse`:

```
contX5 <- function(x) {
   ifelse(5 %in% name$rate, "X5", "")
}
```

The only thing it returns is this:

```
[1] ""
```

How do I change it so that I get the answer for the whole column?

Thanks!

Comment: your logical condition is checking if the numeric value 5 is one of the numeric values of `name$rate`.   Whereas, it seems like what you want to do is `grep()` for the _*string*_ `5` in `name$rate`

Answer (score 1):

`%in%` looks for *exact* matches. In your case, `5 %in% name$rate` only matches the number 5 in the `rate` column.  You can use `grepl()` to find *any* occurrence of `5` in your column.

```
ifelse(grepl(5, name$rate), "X5", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try. I added an example.

```
yourData <- c(10, 5, 125, 100, 50)

ifelse(unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(yourData), ''), function(x) any(x %in% '5'))), 'X5', '')

""   "X5" "X5" ""   "X5"
```